# Filling Nulls from other Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes, df1 and df2.  I would like to fill the nulls in df2 based on the corresponding entry in df1 taking into account the unique identifier (`id`).  Below is the code:

```rb
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"id": [3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
                     "col1": ['mike', 'matt', 'mertha', 'peter', 'tabby', 'carl', 'brian'],
                     "col2": ['645-345', '645-333', '324-543', '123-432', '563-654', '324-123', '902-342'],
                     "col3": ['cat', 'cat','dog', 'none', 't-rex', 'goat', 'snake']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"id": [6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9],
                    "col1": ['peter', 'peter', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                    "col2": ['324-123','324-123', '902-342', '902-332', '902-123', '556-786', '113-786', '901-345'],
                    "col3": ['none', 'none', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})
```

For brevity, I am not kidding when I try everything under the sun on this site and I can't seem to find the answer.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

## Edited:  Expected Output

I would only like to fill in `col1` and `col3`  `np.nan` values.  `None` is just another option. my expected output is as follows:

```rb
df_merged = pd.DataFrame({"id": [6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9],
                    "col1": ['peter', 'peter', 'tabby','tabby', 'tabby',  'carl','carl','brian'],
                    "col2": ['324-123','324-123', '902-342', '902-332', '902-123', '556-786', '113-786', '901-345'],
                    "col3": ['none', 'none', 't-rex', 't-rex', 't-rex', 'goat', 'goat', 'snake']})
```

Comment: Do you want to replace the string `'none'` as well? Also, what's your expected output?

Comment: I will edit the post with the expected output, my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `id` is index in both dataframes, then Erfan's comment should work. Otherwise:

```
(df2.set_index('id')
    .fillna(df1.set_index('id'))
    .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
   id   col1     col2   col3
0   6  peter  324-123   none
1   6  peter  324-123   none
2   7  tabby  902-342  t-rex
3   7  tabby  902-332  t-rex
4   7  tabby  902-123  t-rex
5   8   carl  556-786   goat
6   8   carl  113-786   goat
7   9  brian  901-345  snake
```

Comment: I like this, I'll take a look and respond back if it's what is needed on the larger dataset.  Ultimately, I would like to avoid tampering with the index if possible.  This is part of a pipeline for production and messing with the indices is not recommended by my boss.

Comment: I could kiss you!  This has been a difficult thing for me for whatever reason.  I should have just stepped back and let my mind process it.  Thank you.  Let me ask this, is there any effect on `set_index` with pipeline data?

Comment: No, set_index and reset_index both creates new dataFrame by default.